# VSCode debugging of Node or Electron Main Process bundled with Webpack

Tags: debugging, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, electron

My Electron main process is written with TypeScript and bundled Webpack 2.

Transpilation is done through `ts-loader` and `babel-loader`.

Development mode starts `webpack --watch` with the [main process configuration](https://github.com/Black-Monolith/SuperNova/blob/f65db6384a18245273b13b4041a8c2f2ab5c8aac/webpack/targets/webpack.main.js).

## Problem

I cannot debug the main process using VSCode debugger.

Adding a breakpoint in the entry point `src/main/index.ts` does not have any effect.

## Configuration

#### [`.vscode/launch.js`](https://github.com/Black-Monolith/SuperNova/blob/f65db6384a18245273b13b4041a8c2f2ab5c8aac/.vscode/launch.json)

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

#### [`webpack.development.js`](https://github.com/Black-Monolith/SuperNova/blob/f65db6384a18245273b13b4041a8c2f2ab5c8aac/webpack/targets/webpack.main.js)

```
{
  target: 'electron',
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: {
    main: join(__dirname, 'src/main/index')
  },

  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, 'app'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### VSCode configuration

The important thing is to give VSCode the **source file** which is the entry point of the program, and specify it in `"program"` key.

You also need to specify in `"outFiles"` the bundle generated by Webpack.

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",

      // This is the important stuff
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main/index.ts"
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/app/main.js"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

### Webpack configuration

In your Webpack config you need to specify that you want to write the full paths of the modules source files in your sourcemaps.

```
{
  output: {
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]'
  }
}
```

Also be careful to choose a sourcemap that is not evaluated, to permit VSCode to find the corresponding entry-point statically.

### Minimal example

I created [a repo](https://github.com/kube/vscode-ts-webpack-node-debug-example) with the minimal configuration and more explanations.

Comment: I had to use `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/main.js"` instead of the typescript file. Also, the port was different: `electron ./dist --serve --debug=3068`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's possible or not, but `--remote-debugging-port=9222` is for the v8-inspector protocol, which isn't supported by Electron Node yet (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6634).

Since this is a launch config, VS Code will pass `--debug=5858` to the runtime, so you don't need to specify a port here. Maybe try adding `--nolazy`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just found how to achieve this. In fact I think the `--no-lazy` flag is passed by default. But you're right about the debugging port.